# Dataframe R, add every other row

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

This brief example illustrates the problem. I want to add the same information `Total` and `Value` after every row in my dataframe. The correct `ID` should be given to every new row.

```
data.frame(ID=c('A1','A2'), one=c(1,2), two=c(3,4))
  ID one two
1 A1   1   3
2 A2   2   4
```

The final results should look like this.

```
data.frame(ID=c('A1','A1','A2','A2'), one=c(1,'Total',2,'Total'), two=c(3,'Value',4,'Value'))
  ID   one   two
1 A1     1     3
2 A1 Total Value
3 A2     2     4
4 A2 Total Value
```

I found a few related SO questions, but they don't really answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R version would be

```
#Create a new dataframe with same rows with `ID` value from df
df1 <- data.frame(ID = df$ID, one='Total', two='Value')

#rbind both the dataframes
df2 <- rbind(df, df1)

#Order the new dataframe based on the ID to get alternating rows
df2[order(df2$ID), ]

#  ID   one   two
#1 A1     1     3
#3 A1 Total Value
#2 A2     2     4
#4 A2 Total Value
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c('A1','A2'), one=c(1,2), two=c(3,4))
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit curious about the usefulness of such a transformations, but this is one way to accomplish it:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c('A1','A2'), one=c(1,2), two=c(3,4))

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(one='Total', two='Value') %>% 
  bind_rows(mutate_all(df, as.character)) %>% 
  arrange(ID, one)
```

Output:

```
  ID   one   two
1 A1     1     3
2 A1 Total Value
3 A2     2     4
4 A2 Total Value
```